# Unable to get response

Tags: apex

I created apex class and page for get response from web service but it is not work. I'm not get any response from this code. What wrong in this.
anyone pls help me for this.

This is apex class:

```
public class Temperature123

{

    tempuriOrg.DNSInfo output;

    public pagereference recordReplicator()

    {

        tempuriOrg.DNSSoap stub = new tempuriOrg.DNSSoap();

        stub.LicenseInfo = new wsStrikeironCom.LicenseInfo();

        stub.LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser = new wsStrikeironCom.RegisteredUser();

        stub.LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.UserID = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';

        stub.LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.Password = 'xxxx';
        String nserver = 'google.com';

        System.debug('Server Ips');

        output = stub.DNSLookup(nserver);

        System.Debug('output' + output);

        return page.first_visual_force_page;
    }
    public tempuriOrg.DNSInfo getoutput()

    {

        return output;
    }

}
```

This is my apex page:

```
<apex:page controller="Temperature123">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!recordReplicator}" value="Start"/>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you specify what is not working? Are you getting en exception? Are you getting to the point where you debug your output? More information would be welcome. Also, are you sure that the external WebService works? Have you tested it with, say SoapUI?

Comment: When i click button no action is performed.

Comment: The VF markup looks right to me. Is your recordReplicator() method called at least? You can check this in the dev console